# How to declare a variable only one time in JavaScript helpers?

Tags: javascript, variables, meteor, helper, meteor-blaze

I am developing web components with meteor-blaze.

In Template helpers,

```
Template.Button.helpers({
btnName: function() {
    var FirstBtn = new ButtonComponents('Name', this.class, '50px', '30px', '#DDDDDD');
    return FirstBtn.buttonName();
},
btnClass: function() {
    var FirstBtn = new ButtonComponents('Name', this.class, '50px', '30px', '#DDDDDD');
    return FirstBtn.buttonClass();
},
btnStyle: function() {
    var FirstBtn = new ButtonComponents('Name', this.class, '50px', '30px', '#DDDDDD');
    return FirstBtn.buttonStyle();
}});
```

I want to declare `FirstBtn` only one time in helpers.

I don't want to declare `FirstBtn` outside of helpers because of `this.class`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why does `this.class` prevent you from declaring `FirstBtn` in the outer scope?

Comment: It may be related to self referencing object 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations

Comment: Because I use Inclusion tag(partial) with data context.
`{{> Button class="btn black"}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var FirstBtn;
function getFirstBtn(cls) {
    if (FirstBtn == null) {
        FirstBtn = new ButtonComponents('Name', cls, '50px', '30px', '#DDDDDD');
    }
    return FirstBtn;
}

Template.Button.helpers({
    btnName: function() {
        return getFirstBtn(this.class).buttonName();
    },
    btnClass: function() {
        return getFirstBtn(this.class).buttonClass();
    },
    btnStyle: function() {
        return getFirstBtn(this.class).buttonStyle();
    }
});
```

**Added:** I'd strongly recommend you to create this button in the `onCreated` and store it in the template instance itself. You can later refer to it from helpers like this: `Template.instance().FirstBtn.buttonName()` for example.

Comment: Thanks! It works very well. I will adapt your 'Added' advice!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have an another question. How can I add `this.class` when I create the buttion in the `onCreated`? In `onCreated`, I can't use `this.class`, however, I can only use `this.class` in `helpers`

Comment: Use `this.data.class`

Answer (score 0):

You should put your variable in the Template instance, and access it with **Template.instance()**.

```
Template.Button.onCreated(function(){
    this.FirstBtn = new ButtonComponents('Name', this.data.class, '50px', '30px', '#DDDDDD');
});

Template.Button.helpers({
btnName: function() {
    const instance = Template.instance();

    return instance.FirstBtn.buttonName();
},
btnClass: function() {
    const instance = Template.instance();

    return instance.FirstBtn.buttonClass();
},
btnStyle: function() {
    const instance = Template.instance();

    return instance.FirstBtn.buttonStyle();
}});
```

Writing `const instance = Template.instance();` at the first line of your helper is a good practice recommended by the BlazeJS documentation.